# Fill business object from database by calling stored procedures?

Tags: .net, asp.net, stored-procedures, business-objects

I have several stored procedures in my database, some of them have params, some have no params. I tried to fill a business object by calling the stored procedures, but failed so far. How could I do that dynamically? Later, I want to use this object as a datasource for a report...but thats the next step. The important facts are:

- different stored procs return different amount of columns
- stored procs can have params, but its not required

How could I achieve that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using an ORM, perhaps NHibernate or Linq to SQL? Or are you trying to fill objects via a DataReader or DataSet?

Comment: Nope, in a small demo app I followed this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

And now I was hoping that this can be modified to work dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to scrap the business object code from that article on MSDN[, download NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), go through the [Getting Started guide](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx), and then walk through this [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx) from Ayende.

The objects you create from NHibernate then can be used to bind to the Report Viewer on the MSDN article you referenced in your comment.

Good luck! :)